# Issue Addressing Website on SBS2011

Tags: routing, ipv4

I have a small local network around an SBS2011 server. I would like to host one or more (low-volume) ASP Net Core 2 sites on this server using the standard port 80. However, I am struggling with the networking and apologise if this is a very basic question.

I have a broadband router at 192.168.1.254/24 and the server is 192.168.1.1. Workstations and the server point to the default gateway of 192.168.1.254.

The site which runs fine in VS2017 on localhost has been successfully published to a folder on c: drive of the server. An 'A' record has been set up externally which points subsite.mydomain to the fixed external IP address of the router. I have set IIS with the web site pointing to the site's local folder and have added a binding of subsite.mydomain/external IP/Port 80.

In addition, I have added a server DNS A record with the site name and IP 192.168.1.250 (arbitrary) and an IIS binding of this SiteName/IP/80.

None of these appear to work. From the internal network, the router interface is displayed. Externally, there is just a blank page.

Is this because requests are going straight to the router (default gateway) and are not being interpreted by the server? Should the gateway be on a different subnet? If so, how can I set things up correctly, please (will appreciate simple steps!).

The router is a Technicolor TG588v v2, supplied by my ISP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the necessary port forwarding rule in your router. You need to create a rule that forwards inbound connections made to the router's WAN interface on port 80 to the internal IP address of the server.

> In addition, I have added a server DNS A record with the site name and IP 192.168.1.250 (arbitrary) and an IIS binding of this SiteName/IP/80. None of these appear to work. From the internal network, the router interface is displayed.

I'm not certain what you mean by this, but it sounds like you created a DNS A record on your *internal* DNS server that points the external DNS name (of your router/web server/SBS server) to the public IP address of your router. If so, this probably isn't working because your router is not configured to perform [hairpin NAT](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning?wprov=sfla1).

You can fix this one of two ways:

- Configure your router for hairpin NAT if supported). When configured, hairpin NAT accepts connections from the internal LAN that are destined to the router's WAN IP and then forwards them to the internal server's IP address in the same way it would if the connection originated from the Internet.
- Create a DNS A record on your internal DNS server that points your server's public hostname to the server's private IP address. This works best if all internal clients use your local DNS server instead of one on the Internet.

Comment: Many thanks for this. It solved that problem - I think - error messages changed from 404 to 500! Now need to work out how to debug/resolve the problem with the site. Publish worked perfectly when setting up my last site on a hosting service.